# Using xcassets images as src for img tag in a UIWebView web page

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, xcode5, xcasset

Xcode 5 introduced the possibility to manage all your images in a single assets file, instead of having a bunch of png variants hanging around.

It works great with IB and Cocoa code, but when I try to reference the pictures from an embedded html, they simply do not show.

So the question is simple: is it possible to reference xcasset images from an embedded html in a UIWebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently if you open the app package, the images get all mixed together in a mysterious binary .car format (with the sole exception of the icon and launch image that are still copied as individual files).

Therefore it doesn't seem possible to reference xcassets images from the html source. You'll have to continue to bundle them separately.

Comment: Yes, it is still the case as I cannot access an image with or without extension from html inside webview.